# Do we need both [currency] and [money] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The [currency](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currency) and [money](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) tags have 16 and eight questions, respectively. I can’t think of a reason why we would need both tags. Should one of them be made a synonym of the other? Or should questions be re-tagged so that one of the tags is removed?

Comment: [Last time](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9256/make-x2-and-x-men-2-synonyms) I suggested making tags synonyms, I never found out for sure whether my request was even possible. Maybe nobody has enough [tag:currency] and [tag:money] rep to vote on synonyms...

Comment: That's what mods are for: to help out when there aren't enough users with enough rep to deal with some issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Done](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/money/synonyms).

Both tags have been merged and synonymised, with [money](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) as the master tag.